how can anchor program A read account data from anchor program B with #account macro way?
My anchor program "A", expect to use data from a anchor program name "B".
Let's say program_b (which I don't have code, just know it's address) has declare PDA account data struct:
#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)] 
pub struct FeeData {
    pub fee: u64,
}

and I got this account address that pass into program_a.
And in program_a, related code is:
        ...
#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)] 
pub struct FeeData {     // mock after the struct on program_b
    pub fee: u64,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
        ...
/// CHECK: no check purposely
pub fee_from_prog_b: Account<'info, FeeData>,
        ...
}

But, once invode instruction on program_a, I got error:
Error Code: AccountDiscriminatorMismatch. Error Number: 3002. Error Message: 8 byte discriminator did not match what was expected.'
I know there is account discriminator and why this error raise.
After search in the forumn, I got this one:
How to Deserialize Anchor Accounts from Other Programs in Accounts Struct    but I don't like this way to make it work.
Edit:
I would like an #account attribute way, or hand coding to read that out(but I don't know how to).
So, I'm looking for a better solution to this requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Finally, I figure it out. This is my solution


#[derive(Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct FeeData {
    pub fee: u64,
}

#[program]
pub mod test_program {
    use super::*;
 
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {

        let fee_account = ctx.accounts.fee_ata.to_account_info();
        let fee_data = FeeData::try_from_slice(&fee_account.data.borrow()[..][8..]).expect("Should success");

        msg!("initialize: {:?}", fee_data.fee);
        msg!("initialize:  owner {:?}", fee_account.owner);

        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {

    /// CHECK:
    pub fee_ata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}


Import from program B namespace the typed account.
use program_b::{  
    state::FeeData,
};

If you need to use any ix from program B you can make use of CPI namespace that's can be included as a feature in your Cargo.tomk
When importing program B
program-b = { path = "../program-b", features = ["cpi"] }


Thanks, I know this approach. But I don't have the program mod of program_b, and dislike to create a stub program_b mod.
